# Can the loading message of an Android Listview be customized?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Before an Android Listview is populated it shows a 'Loading' message for a few milliseconds. Is it possible to either customize this message (textsize, alignment, wording) or to remove it completely?

On my App Widget the textsize of the message is too big, so only the upper half of the message is visible. This looks really ugly.

I thought it would be possible to specify a custom view for this like you can do with setEmptyView() for when the adapter is empty but I didn't find anything in the documentation.

**EDIT:**

Ok, nevermind, I got it. I was looking at the wrong place. The Listview indeed doesn't have an option for this. To populate, I'm using a RemoteViewsService that returns a RemoteViewsFactory. The factory has the method getLoadingView() that does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How do you populate your listview ? Default behaviour does not to show any Loading message, it must be set somewhere. Please, show your code.

Comment: is it the example application you´re running?

Comment: I was going through my code again to post the important parts when I suddenly saw the solution. I edited my post above. But thanks for your effort guys!